# Weird returns from sqlite

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite

I've got 2 very similar queries running to my sqlite file.

1:

```
SELECT * 
FROM gca_logged 
WHERE UserID='39' 
  AND dateStamp LIKE '%09/16/2016' 
ORDER BY uniqueID DESC
```

2:

```
SELECT * 
FROM gca_logged 
WHERE UserID='39' 
 AND dateStamp LIKE '%%'
ORDER BY uniqueID DESC
```

**My problem is `WHERE UserID='39' AND dateStamp LIKE '%%'` returns nothing but `WHERE UserID='39' AND dateStamp LIKE '%09/16/2016'` returns the expected amount of rows.**

**Similarly, I have code on the page that doesn't use the UserID at all, for example `WHERE dateStamp LIKE '%%` & `WHERE dateStamp LIKE'%09/16/2016%` and those also return the expected output. So the problem only persists when I try to search with the UserID AND `dateStamp LIKE '%%'`**

2 is the same query as 1 but without the datestamp check.

Now, here is the weird part; query 1 returns the correct amount of rows expected. Basically the amount of rows inputted for that day.

Row 2 returns 0 rows. Row 2 should return all rows inputted for user 39 - but it returns 0.

I'm having a really hard time understanding this.

my code:

```
    @$dEx = explode("-",$_GET['date']);
    $searchDate2 = $dEx[1]."/".$dEx[2]."/".$dEx[0]; //m/d/Y -> Y-m-d

    if (0 === strpos($searchDate2, '//')) {
        $searchDate2 = substr($searchDate2, 2);
    }

    if(strcmp($_GET['date'],"showAllTime") == 0) {
        $searchDate2 = "";
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM gca_logged WHERE UserID='".$_GET['adminSearch']."' AND dateStamp LIKE '%$searchDate2%' ORDER BY uniqueID DESC";
```

I tried the code `$sql = "SELECT * FROM gca_logged WHERE UserID='".$_GET['adminSearch']."' AND dateStamp LIKE '%".$searchDate2."%' ORDER BY uniqueID DESC";` as suggested in the comments, with no difference.

(If _GET['date'] equals showAllTime the date variable is set to "". When echoing the $sql variables, they appear to be correct.

This method works elsewhere on the website, just not for this page.

semi-related code I removed earlier:

```
    if((isSet($_GET['all'])) && ($_GET['all'] == 1)) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM gca_logged WHERE dateStamp LIKE '%$searchDate2%' ORDER BY uniqueID DESC";
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM gca_logged WHERE UserID='".$_GET['adminSearch']."' AND dateStamp LIKE '%".$searchDate2."%' ORDER BY uniqueID DESC";
    }
```

These are 2 **different** queries, one with the UserID and one without. When the if variable is correct, as in using the query without the UserID, it works just like it should - returning all the results or just the selected day.

So my problem is not the query **without** the UserID, it's the query **with** the UserID.

Comment: @Darren You are looking at the wrong $sql statement. That is a completely different and unrelated one. And I made a typo in the examples

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Your code and your querys doesnt match.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Just fixed it.

Comment: Your code will blow up when [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) shows up.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton stilll doesnt match

Comment: @Darren the one with the UserID is related. The one without it is not related.

Comment: @Darren Updated to remove unrelated code.

Comment: If the problem is with the sql what you show us php code? did you miss a `%` in first query? I dont see how first query will bring a bigger result than second one so your problem is somewhere else

Comment: what type is `dateStamp` ??

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I showed you the PHP code so you could see that the sql query is dynamic. The `$searchDate2` variable changes depending on a get variable. The 1st variable return should be smaller than the 2nd, but the 2nd one returns nothing. That is my problem.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza dateStamp is text.

Comment: instead of `LIKE '%$searchDate2%'` shouldnt be `LIKE '%'. $searchDate2. '%'`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza That shouldn't make a difference, I would expect that to be the problem if I had the opposite problem than I have.

Comment: Did you try query 1 and 2 direct on db?

Comment: @Darren like I said in the post, when I echo the $sql variables, they echo properly containing the variable. I will try it to confirm it doesn't make a difference, but I'm fairly sure it won't.

Comment: @Darren Yes, I have inspected them. On the same page I echo the `$sql` variable, which is just a string, for bugtesting. They are the correct output, it either echos it as `%09/16/2016%` or `%%`. So yes, I have specifically checked this already, and if was the issue to begin with, the query wouldn't work when the date is selected.

Comment: As I said your assumptions are wrong test the query in the DB. Check this [**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0c9a4e/2) and you will see works as expected. Feel free to update that fiddle with a case to reproduce your error.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I'm not sure how to reproduce the issue because I'm not sure what the issue is. Your fiddle only proves my point. I work with SQL all day long pretty much everyday, that is why I am having such a hard time figuring out what is wrong here, because it should be working.

Comment: @Darren I readded the code with an explanation of why it is somewhat relevant. And I'm editing in hopes to make it easier to find the problem that I can't spot. Sorry if my reponses are coming off as rude, I honestly am not trying to, I'm just aggravated by this code that i have used dozens of times in the same project and it's not working in this once instance

Comment: We are not harry potter. I prove your query should work. that mean the problem isnt the query. Looks somewhere else. Create a duplicate db/tables, start adding thing until the query broke. Maybe is a trigger or a function causing your the issue but we **cant** guess that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123565/discussion-between-grumpycrouton-and-juan-carlos-oropeza).

Comment: btw stop with the **BOLD**,  that looks like you are angry. Take your time to format the text so is easy for other to read. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the wrong things

Your querys

```
SELECT * 
FROM gca_logged 
WHERE UserID='39' 
  AND dateStamp LIKE '%09/16/2016' 
ORDER BY uniqueID DESC

SELECT * 
FROM gca_logged 
WHERE UserID='39' 
 AND dateStamp LIKE '%%'
ORDER BY uniqueID DESC
```

Your Code, show one doesnt even select `userID`

```
SELECT * 
FROM gca_logged 
WHERE dateStamp LIKE '%09/16/2016%' 
ORDER BY uniqueID DESC

SELECT * 
FROM gca_logged 
WHERE UserID='39' 
 AND dateStamp LIKE '%09/16/2016%'
ORDER BY uniqueID DESC
```

Comment: You were mistaken with unrelated code. Please check my updates.